# Displaying column names for each row in Pandas dataframe over specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with Python Pandas Dataframe and trying to print a list of columns for each row in my dataset, assume that each column can have a 0 or 1 value. Eg:

```
id   A   B    C   D
 0   1   1    1   1
 1   0   1    0   1
 2   1   1    0   0
 3   1   0    0   0
```

Now, I need my output to be:

```
id   output
 0   A,B,C,D
 1   B,D
 2   A,B
 3   A
```

Please note that I need to prepare a generic function irrespective of column names or number.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
df = df.assign(output=df.dot(df.columns))

df[['output']]

id   output
 0   A,B,C,D
 1   B,D
 2   A,B
 3   A
```

Comment: Wonderful answer!

Comment: Please dont upvote this. :( it's a variation of the answer I flagged.

Comment: Ah, well, you do learn from the best after all.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ surprised to not see your name there, seemed it was every big pythonSO'er

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ you're in the comments :p

Comment: Yeah... I'd commented on it the next day... I remember prepping for a test, and wasn't on SO much that day, ended up missing out... Ah well we can't have the cake and eat it too.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  @GiantsLoveDeathMetal